# Diffie Hellman Key Exhange not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I tried to create the Diffie Hellman key exchange system in javascript **without plugins**. My code unfortunately doesn't work and often creates 2 *different* secret keys.

Code:

```
var g = next_Prime_num(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50));
var n = next_Prime_num(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50) + 50);
    
var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (n - 1));
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (n - 1));

var A = mod(Math.pow(g, a), n);
var B = mod(Math.pow(g, b), n);
    
var Ka = mod(Math.pow(B, a), n);
var Kb = mod(Math.pow(A, b), n);
    
    

function next_Prime_num(num) {
    for (var i = num + 1;; i++) {
        var isPrime = true;
        for (var d = 2; d * d <= i; d++) {
            if (i % d === 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
    
function mod(n, m) {
    return n%m;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n: must be a prime number yes, but
g: must be a primitive root of n, and not a just prime number
this is your mistake, you have to add another function to get a primitive root from the givin prim number

Answer (score 0):

The Math.pow() in there is definitely going to have integer overflows every now and then. In javascript the maximum integer you can have without loosing precision or maximum safe integer is `(253 - 1)` or `9007199254740991` .
What you can do is create a power function which uses [modular exponentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-exponentiation).

Check out this similar question - [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange with Javascript sometimes wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677932/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-with-javascript-sometimes-wrong)